# What alternative to Browsermob proxy can I choose?

Tags: selenium, proxy, browsermob-proxy

This tool is almost all good, but there are nuances that I basically do not like in his work. Their discussion can be made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54871517/browsermob-proxy-sends-proxy-authorization-header-after-authorization-on-chained), but now interests me is: what tool can I choose to replace BMP? The requirements are as follows:

- Ability to work through API
- Ability to work not just as a proxy, but as a proxy manager, to create separate living proxies, with all their individual settings, and manage them using the API
- Correctly work with proxy chains
- Living as a standalone application, or as a php project (this is of course unlikely), or as a project that has an SDK for PHP.

What can you advise?

Answer (score 2):

I use several different proxies depending on my need.  I'll list them here.

1. Browsermob Proxy
2. WireMock : http://wiremock.org
3. Charles Proxy : https://www.charlesproxy.com/

Charles is not going to meet the needs that you laid out, but check on WireMock.